# .htaccess wildcard subdomain path

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, subdomain

I have my site set up like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /user/profile.php?name=%1 [L]
```

What this does is if user visits: `test.example.com`, it will show contents of file: `example.com/user/profile.php?name=test`. If someone goes to `lol.example.com`, it will show page: `example.com/user/profile.php?name=lol` but the URL will remain the same with the subdomain, like `test.example.com` and `lol.example.com`.

That part is working.

---

**Question:**

If I go to `test.example.com/login`, it will show my domain root file. How can I make it so that it will show things from the `/user` folder?

For example:

- `test.example.com/login` will show `example.com/user/login` and `test.example.com/register` will show `example.com/user/register` but the URL will remain the same with the subdomain?
- `test.example.com/pathtofile` should get the contents of `example.com/user/pathtofile`. "pathtofile" should be dynamic. I just want the path to look in the folder `/user`, not the root folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if someone goes to `lol.example.com`, it will show page: `example.com/user/profile.php?name=lol`.

Strictly speaking, it will show the page: `lol.example.com/user/profile.php?name=lol` (the subdomain is not removed). But since (I assume) all the subdomains and main domain point to the same place on the filesystem, it works.

> `test.example.com/pathtofile` should get the contents of `example.com/user/pathtofile`

Your original directive only rewrites a request for the document root (`test.example.com/`). To rewrite `/pathtofile` then you can add another rule block after the above in `.htaccess`. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} [^.]+\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)$
RewriteRule !^user/ /user/%1 [L]
```

This rewrites all requests that don't already start `/user/` and that consist of just a single (non-zero length) path segment, as in your example (eg. `/pathtofile` and not `/path/to/file`), and rewrites to `/user/pathtofile`.

**UPDATE:** If you have an `ErrorDocument` defined then you will need to make an exception earlier in your `.htaccess file to prevent subrequests for the error document from being rewritten. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^404\.php$ - [L]
```

Comment: awesome, thats what i needed! also, why is there no 404 error? i have `ErrorDocument 404 /404.php` in my .htaccess but it applies to all other pages except for `subdomain.example.com/pathtofile` if its a 404. **EDIT**: now it is redirecting everything from that is NOT a subdomain to /user/{page}. how can i make it so that it only looks in the folder "user" if it is a subdomain?

Comment: Ah yes, you will need to add the two conditions you had in your first rule block that check for the subdomain. You will need to add an exception for your `ErrorDocument` URL, to prevent this from being rewritten. Note that this rewrites _everything_ eg. `/<anything>` to `/user/<anything>`. I've updated my answer.